# Search Function only works with one variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, search

I have this Code and it works perfectly, but as soon as I want to write more LIKE Operators my whole gridview changes.

Example: I want:

```sql
AND (Number LIKE '%' + @Number + '%') OR (Place LIKE '%' + @Place + '%')
```

```cs
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Number", txtSearch.Text.Trim());
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Place ", txtSearch.Text.Trim());
```

my Gridview ignores the session and on Login you can see every users data.

Login is the username.

but If I keep it like this it works perfectly:

```cs
 protected void btnFilter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string name = Session["user"].ToString();

        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["strConn"].ConnectionString;

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {

            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT * From Product
                                           Inner Join User
                                           ON product.user = user.id
                                           Where user.login = @User
                                           AND Status = @Status
                                           AND (Number LIKE '%' + @Number + '%')";

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@User", name);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Number", txtSearch.Text.Trim());

                using (SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    ad.Fill(dt);
                    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                    GridView1.DataBind();
                }
            }
        }
```

```xml
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1"  DataKeyNames="Number" AllowSorting="true" OnRowDataBound="RowDataBound"  runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" SortExpression="ID" Visible="false" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Number" HeaderText="Nummer" SortExpression="Number" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Login" HeaderText="Datum" SortExpression="Login" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Date" HeaderText="Datum" SortExpression="Date" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Try to put the % not in the sql but inside the value cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Number", "%" + txtSearch.Text.Trim() + "%");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to group your `OR` in the correct parenthesis, otherwise it gets `OR`ed against all of the other filters.  It's basic boolean algebra:

A and B and C or D will return true any time D is true

A and B and (C or D) will return true only if A, B, and (C or D) are true.

Change

```
AND (Number LIKE '%' + @Number + '%') OR (Place LIKE '%' + @Place + '%')
```

to

```
AND ((Number LIKE '%' + @Number + '%') OR (Place LIKE '%' + @Place + '%'))
```